# What is the most efficient way to search for multiple tokens in one string using PHP?

Tags: php

We would like to examine all incoming GET/POST data for malicious code. If detected, we want to issue a ban from the server. I'm a little concerned about performance though searching through all the data.

Using PHP, we are currently doing something like this:

```
$t = $_POST['example'];
if(
    (strpos($t, 'hex') && strpos($t, 'unhex')) || 
    (strpos($t, 'etc') && strpos($t, 'passwd')) || 
    strpos($t, 'information_schema')
  )
  // Initiate ban of IP
```

Is there are  more efficient way to do this? The goal is to not waste resources on "bad requests." We use prepared statements, so it's a performance question rather than security. The blacklisting occurs at the Juniper level which means the database servers, file servers, etc. don't strain at all after an initial bad request.

FYI: Programs like OSSEC are too slow on the draw. They often allow 20-40 requests to get processed before it actually reacts and begins the banning process. At the application layer, we can catch the first request. This may seem inconsequential, but when you're being attacked by 100+ IP addresses it makes a huge difference to catch the first request.

Comment: I wouldn't bother. IP bans are pretty easy to avoid. As long as you are using prepared statement you should be fine, DOOS protection should be done server side on the backend layer of your server.

Comment: I'm not writing an information exchange application like Stack Overflow. If I were I would look for a different solution. We are in an environment where young minds like to experiment with malicious attacks that often strain the servers.

Comment: You appear to be attempting a blacklist approach to security. Just be advised that this never works. There are virtually infinitely many variations of "bad stuff", you cannot filter them all.

Comment: If the cost of inspecting each request is higher than allowing 20-40 requests to pass unchecked the latter is probably a better deal. You can never prevent an attack, you can only try to limit the damage. Shooting yourself in the proverbial foot doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Hey Halcyon -- good suggestion but rate limiting is difficult. Many universities who access our information all come from one IP address. If a class of students were to visit the website at the same time, it would all register under one IP address.

Comment: What are you doing with `$t` that you think you need to examine it for malicious code?  Are you going to execute code passed to you from the outside?  If so, that's a much bigger question than just doing many string checks.

Comment: $t represents all data coming in from user input. We have a central class file that collections all GET/POST data. The idea is to verify the data before allowing it to be passed on. At this point in the application level, it hasn't been determined what the data will be used for: maybe a query, perhaps its account data being contributed by a user.

Comment: This is a performance question. Instead of allowing a bot to execute 5-8 queries on the page with bad data, I would rather detect the bad data and put a ban in place. Using 8-10 keywords most "bots" that run SQL injection attacks DO use the same lingo. I'm confident we can eliminate 80-90% of the typical attacks, but I want to know the most EFFICIENT way to do it. If you are here to debate security find another question -- if you have an opinion on efficiently looking for multiple tokens in a string, please contribute.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is to blacklist certain expressions that you may receive through the form.
This is not the most effective practice, since an attacker could use alternatives that you didn't considered, in order to bypass your controls.

A best practice to prevent sql injection is whitelisting the content, according to what you want to allow.

The following is from [Cisco website on SQL injection](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/sql_injection.html):

> Within an application itself, there are two approaches to input
>   validation that can defend against SQL injection attacks: blacklisting
>   and whitelisting. With blacklisting, specific, known malicious
>   characters are removed from or replaced in user input. Although this
>   approach is often implemented, largely due to the ease at which it can
>   be accomplished, it is not effective when compared to whitelisting.
>   Blacklisting can fail to properly handle complex obfuscation, which
>   could allow an attacker to subvert filters and potentially inject SQL
>   statements. This failure often occurs as a result of evolving attack
>   techniques and filters that are not comprehensive or not implemented
>   correctly.
>
> Alternately, whitelisting examines each piece of user input against a
>   list of permitted characters. This approach is more effective in
>   mitigating the risk of SQL injection, as it is more restrictive
>   concerning which types of input are allowed. Well-implemented
>   whitelisting should examine each piece of user-supplied data against
>   the expected data format.

Depending on the kind of approach you use and on the kind of data you expect to receive, you'll have different performance to check for SQL injection.

Comment: Again, it's not a security question as much as it is a performance question. The attacks we see are very consistent with their input. It's easy to detect, and rather than letting the page execute 5-8 queries we'd rather just stop/ban to reduce load.